# How can I find which serial port is connected to Nucleo board via ST-LINK?

Tags: microcontroller, serial, communication, st-link, nucleo

I have a Nucleo board connected via USB to ST-Link running on Ubuntu Linux.  ST-Link works well in that it can program the board.  I would like to use the built in virtual serial port, but am not sure how to do this.

When I use mbed, the mbed serial drivers works.  However, I'm trying to use direct serial connections on Linux via `minicom` or `tio`, but can't find the appropriate `/dev/tty????`.  The listing seems to be the same whether or not the Nucleo is connected.

I *am* able to program the board properly and even run `st-util` and `gdb`.  How can I find the virtual serial port?

```
$ st-info --probe
Found 1 stlink programmers
  version:    V2J33S25
  serial:     066BFF575383564867173843
  flash:      524288 (pagesize: 131072)
  sram:       131072
  chipid:     0x0421
  descr:      F446
```

```
$ tio --list
```

(no output)

```
$ ls -l /dev/ | sort -n | grep ttyS
crw-rw----  1 root  dialout   4,  64 Sep  3 20:23 ttyS0
...
crw-rw----  1 root  dialout   4,  95 Sep  2 16:08 ttyS31
```

(all seem to be there even without Nucleo)

---

## Update

Or, perhaps the question isn't how to *find* it, but how to
*create* it? It seems like st-link may not do this automatically on Linux.  [ST docs](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/ST-LINK#Connecting_UART_port_-28from_ST-LINK-2FV2-1-29) state:

> Users must be granted with rights for accessing ST-Link USB devices. Rules must then be added into /etc/udev/rules.d.
>
> All information and files for installing the udev rules are provided in the STSW-LINK007[6] package available from [www.st.com](http://www.st.com) (see stsw-link007\AllPlatforms\StlinkRulesFilesForLinux\Readme.txt file).

However, the link to the package docs is 404.  I found it manually, and installed the Debian udev rules, but still can't find any serial port.

---

Below are diffs of dmesg and lsusb, as well as a full ls of ttys.  You can see the ST-Link, but I can't find the virtual com port.  `VCP` is mentioned, but not with a `/dev/tty*` or even `/dev` associated with it (unless I am misreading?).

```
--- dmesg_without_nucleo.txt    2023-09-04 14:43:05.979884220 -0400
+++ dmesg_add_nucleo.txt        2023-09-04 14:43:39.003081488 -0400
@@ -2383,3 +2383,19 @@
 [303048.824125] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
 [304451.301945] usb 2-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 17
 [304451.364540] FAT-fs (sdb): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
+[304476.677994] usb 2-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 18 using uhci_hcd
+[304477.034132] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=374b0
+[304477.034139] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNum3
+[304477.034141] usb 2-2.1: Product: STM32 STLink
+[304477.034144] usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
+[304477.034145] usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: 066BFF575383564867173843
+[304477.085183] usb-storage 2-2.1:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
+[304477.087893] scsi host33: usb-storage 2-2.1:1.1
+[304478.122213] scsi 33:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MBED     microcontroller  1.02
+[304478.122797] scsi 33:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
+[304478.128400] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] 1096 512-byte logical blocks: (561 kB/548 K)
+[304478.131636] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
+[304478.131642] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
+[304478.134436] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
+[304478.134443] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
+[304478.288328] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

```
--- lsusb_without_nucleo.txt    2023-09-04 14:46:03.733315924 -0400
+++ lsusb_with_nucleo.txt       2023-09-04 14:45:47.814262450 -0400
@@ -67,6 +67,176 @@
 Device Status:     0x0001
   Self Powered

+Bus 002 Device 018: ID 0483:374b STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2.1
+Device Descriptor:
+  bLength                18
+  bDescriptorType         1
+  bcdUSB               2.00
+  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
+  bDeviceSubClass         2
+  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
+  bMaxPacketSize0        64
+  idVendor           0x0483 STMicroelectronics
+  idProduct          0x374b ST-LINK/V2.1
+  bcdDevice            1.00
+  iManufacturer           1 STMicroelectronics
+  iProduct                2 STM32 STLink
+  iSerial                 3 066BFF575383564867173843
+  bNumConfigurations      1
+  Configuration Descriptor:
+    bLength                 9
+    bDescriptorType         2
+    wTotalLength       0x0080
+    bNumInterfaces          4
+    bConfigurationValue     1
+    iConfiguration          0
+    bmAttributes         0x80
+      (Bus Powered)
+    MaxPower              300mA
+    Interface Descriptor:
+      bLength                 9
+      bDescriptorType         4
+      bInterfaceNumber        0
+      bAlternateSetting       0
+      bNumEndpoints           3
+      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
+      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
+      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
+      iInterface              4 ST-Link Debug
+      Endpoint Descriptor:
+        bLength                 7
+        bDescriptorType         5
+        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
+        bmAttributes            2
+          Transfer Type            Bulk
+          Synch Type               None
+          Usage Type               Data
+        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
+        bInterval               0
+      Endpoint Descriptor:
+        bLength                 7
+        bDescriptorType         5
+        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
+        bmAttributes            2
+          Transfer Type            Bulk
+          Synch Type               None
+          Usage Type               Data
+        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
+        bInterval               0
+      Endpoint Descriptor:
+        bLength                 7
+        bDescriptorType         5
+        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
+        bmAttributes            2
+          Transfer Type            Bulk
+          Synch Type               None
+          Usage Type               Data
+        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
+        bInterval               0
+    Interface Descriptor:
+      bLength                 9
+      bDescriptorType         4
+      bInterfaceNumber        1
+      bAlternateSetting       0
+      bNumEndpoints           2
+      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
+      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
+      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
+      iInterface              5 ST-Link mass storage
+      Endpoint Descriptor:
+        bLength                 7
+        bDescriptorType         5
+        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
+        bmAttributes            2
+          Transfer Type            Bulk
+          Synch Type               None
+          Usage Type               Data
+        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
+        bInterval               0
+      Endpoint Descriptor:
+        bLength                 7
+        bDescriptorType         5
+        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
+        bmAttributes            2
+          Transfer Type            Bulk
+          Synch Type               None
+          Usage Type               Data
+        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
+        bInterval               0
+    Interface Association:
+      bLength                 8
+      bDescriptorType        11
+      bFirstInterface         2
+      bInterfaceCount         2
+      bFunctionClass          2 Communications
+      bFunctionSubClass       2 Abstract (modem)
+      bFunctionProtocol       1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
+      iFunction               6 ST-Link VCP Ctrl
+    Interface Descriptor:
+      bLength                 9
+      bDescriptorType         4
+      bInterfaceNumber        2
+      bAlternateSetting       0
+      bNumEndpoints           1
+      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
+      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
+      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
+      iInterface              6 ST-Link VCP Ctrl
+      CDC Header:
+        bcdCDC               1.10
+      CDC Call Management:
+        bmCapabilities       0x00
+        bDataInterface          3
+      CDC ACM:
+        bmCapabilities       0x06
+          sends break
+          line coding and serial state
+      CDC Union:
+        bMasterInterface        2
+        bSlaveInterface         3
+      Endpoint Descriptor:
+        bLength                 7
+        bDescriptorType         5
+        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
+        bmAttributes            3
+          Transfer Type            Interrupt
+          Synch Type               None
+          Usage Type               Data
+        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
+        bInterval             255
+    Interface Descriptor:
+      bLength                 9
+      bDescriptorType         4
+      bInterfaceNumber        3
+      bAlternateSetting       0
+      bNumEndpoints           2
+      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
+      bInterfaceSubClass      0
+      bInterfaceProtocol      0
+      iInterface              7 ST-Link VCP Data
+      Endpoint Descriptor:
+        bLength                 7
+        bDescriptorType         5
+        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
+        bmAttributes            2
+          Transfer Type            Bulk
+          Synch Type               None
+          Usage Type               Data
+        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
+        bInterval               0
+      Endpoint Descriptor:
+        bLength                 7
+        bDescriptorType         5
+        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
+        bmAttributes            2
+          Transfer Type            Bulk
+          Synch Type               None
+          Usage Type               Data
+        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
+        bInterval               0
+Device Status:     0x0000
+  (Bus Powered)
+
 Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
 Device Descriptor:
   bLength                18
@@ -126,7 +296,7 @@
   DeviceRemovable    0x00
   PortPwrCtrlMask    0xfe
  Hub Port Status:
-   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
+   Port 1: 0000.0103 power enable connect
    Port 2: 0000.0100 power
    Port 3: 0000.0100 power
    Port 4: 0000.0100 power
@@ -253,6 +423,6 @@
   PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
  Hub Port Status:
    Port 1: 0000.0103 power enable connect
-   Port 2: 0000.0107 power suspend enable connect
+   Port 2: 0000.0103 power enable connect
 Device Status:     0x0001
   Self Powered
```

```
# ls -l -t /dev/tty*
```

### (no STLink - full output removed due to length)

### Follow Up Questions

Do you have any leads how I could debug this? I switched to a powered USB hub - no change.  I updated the firmware - no change. Could it be a problem with the stlink driver - should I somehow try to reinstall it?

I installed mbed and see it can't find the serial port either:

```
$ mbed-tools detect
Board name     Serial number             Serial port    Mount point(s)         n
-------------  ------------------------  -------------  ------------------------
NUCLEO-F446RE  066BFF575383564867173843  <unknown>      /media/srobertjames/NOD_F446RE8
```

How does stlink set up a virtual com port? I'm happy to try to debug that if I know where to look - but I can find no docs on that.

Should I try using different versions (or implementations) of st-link? Is there some type of USB driver that may need reinstall? Please point me in promising ways to explore.

---

## Update

I've rebooted and now the COM port shows!

```
$ tio -L
/dev/serial/by-id/usb-STMicroelectronics_STM32_STLink_066BFF575383564867173843-if02
```

I'm not sure what the cause was, or why the reboot solved it.

Comment: What does dmesg say about devices found when Nucleo is plugged in? Or lsusb (with appropriate number of verbose flags)?

Comment: @Justme Edited with diff.  It shows the ST-Link, it mentions VCP, but shows no com port.

Answer (score 1):

USB serial ports may appear as ttyACM0 or ttyUSB0 - grep ttyS won't show those...

Comment: Thanks.  I've added a full `ls -lt /dev/tty*` to the OP - but still no virtual COM port!